# Bootstrap 4 : Center an image in a flex-row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have a flex-row with 3 components : [TEXT, IMG, TEXT].
I want the IMG to be centered (at the perfect center).

I'm trying to make my 2 paragraphs the same width so my IMG is centered.

Here's my code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="jumbotron shadow-sm">

    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start flex-grow-1 ml-3">
            <p>Small content on the left</p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-grow-1">
            <img src="https://d1guu6n8gz71j.cloudfront.net/system/video/previews/1939344/big.png?1549617786" width="100px">
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end flex-grow-1 mr-3">
            <p>very big content on the right very big content on the right</p>
         </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I've read that I can use flex-basis, I tried, with no satisfying results. I should be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using  [`col`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#equal-width) class

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="jumbotron shadow-sm">

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">

    <div class="col">
      <p>Small content on the left</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col text-center">
      <img src="https://d1guu6n8gz71j.cloudfront.net/system/video/previews/1939344/big.png?1549617786" width="100px">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <p>very big content on the right very big content on the right</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```